# Deployment of Minio using Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minio

Kubernetes Docker Minio not working as [documented](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/storage/minio).

How to connect the browser to the MinIO Server?

Issue Number 1: minio-service URL http://127.0.0.1:52506 gets redirected to http://127.0.0.1:37085/

Issue Number 2: Tried changing minio-service ports in vain:

```
% minikube service minio-service         
|-----------|---------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME      | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | minio-service |       45895 | http://192.168.49.2:32140 |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Starting tunnel for service minio-service.
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME      | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | minio-service |             | http://127.0.0.1:52534 |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------------------|
  Opening service default/minio-service in default browser...
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

[image: minio-service]

**NB**
Earlier in the day, connection to Browser to the MinIO Server (http://127.0.0.1:9090) via docker run was successful as in the following terminal output details:

```
% docker run \
   -p 9000:9000 \
   -p 9090:9090 \
   --name minio \
   -v /Users/macbookprom1apple/Desktop/Working/Docker/minio/data:/data \
   -e "MINIO_ROOT_USER=ROOTNAME" \
   -e "MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=CHANGEME123" \
   quay.io/minio/minio server /data --console-address ":9090"
[
Unable to find image 'quay.io/minio/minio:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from minio/minio
b650cfbb2837: Pull complete 
e9d5ce196263: Pull complete 
c1b201109fa1: Pull complete 
26d5f7e47938: Pull complete 
e3dbc49ce3d2: Pull complete 
a6bfa4552f85: Pull complete 
1ff33655e246: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:8871650797a40e6094828e86709f3e7180615f03d72ea9d385a720dfb2b63510
Status: Downloaded newer image for quay.io/minio/minio:latest
Formatting 1st pool, 1 set(s), 1 drives per set.
WARNING: Host local has more than 0 drives of set. A host failure will result in data becoming unavailable.
MinIO Object Storage Server
Copyright: 2015-2023 MinIO, Inc.
License: GNU AGPLv3 <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html>
Version: RELEASE.2023-11-01T18-37-25Z (go1.21.3 linux/arm64)

Status:         1 Online, 0 Offline. 
S3-API: http://172.17.0.2:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000 
Console: http://172.17.0.2:9090 http://127.0.0.1:9090 

Documentation: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/index.html
Warning: The standard parity is set to 0. This can lead to data loss.
```

**Step 1: Create Persistent Volume Claim**
Minio needs persistent storage to store objects. If there is no persistent storage, the data stored in Minio instance will be stored in the container file system and will be wiped off as soon as the container restarts.

Create a persistent volume claim (PVC) to request storage for the Minio instance. Kubernetes looks out for PVs matching the PVC request in the cluster and binds it to the PVC automatically.

**Step 2: Create Minio Deployment**
A deployment encapsulates replica sets and pods — so, if a pod goes down, replication controller makes sure another pod comes up automatically. This way you won’t need to bother about pod failures and will have a stable Minio service available.

**Step 3: Create Minio Service**
Now that you have a Minio deployment running, you may either want to access it internally (within the cluster) or expose it as a Service onto an external (outside of your cluster, maybe public internet) IP address, depending on your use case. You can achieve this using Services. There are 3 major service types — default type is ClusterIP, which exposes a service to connection from inside the cluster. NodePort and LoadBalancer are two types that expose services to external traffic, and expose the Minio Deployment by creating a LoadBalancer service.

This is the PVC/deployment/service description.

**minio.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  # This name uniquely identifies the PVC. Will be used in deployment below.
  name: minio-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: minio-storage-claim
spec:
  # Read more about access modes here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/#access-modes
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: standard
  resources:
    # This is the request for storage. Should be available in the cluster.
    requests:
      # storage: 256Mi
      storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 #  for k8s versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2  and before 1.8.0 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # This name uniquely identifies the Deployment
  name: minio-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minio
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        # Label is used as selector in the service.
        app: minio
    spec:
      # Refer to the PVC created earlier
      volumes:
      - name: storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          # Name of the PVC created earlier
          claimName: minio-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: minio
        # Pulls the default Minio image from Docker Hub
        image: minio/minio:latest
        args:
        - server
        - /storage
        env:
        # Minio access key and secret key
        - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
          value: "minio"
        - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
          value: "minio123"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          hostPort: 9000
        # Mount the volume into the pod
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage # must match the volume name, above
          mountPath: "/storage"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: minio
```

**Terminal Output:**

```
Last login: Mon Nov  6 18:04:37 on ttys000
% sw_vers                        
ProductName:        macOS
ProductVersion:     14.0
BuildVersion:       23A344
% arch   
arm64
% docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35+desktop.5
 Version:           24.0.6
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.7
 Git commit:        ed223bc
 Built:             Mon Sep  4 12:28:49 2023
 OS/Arch:           darwin/arm64
 Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.25.0 (126437)
 Engine:
  Version:          24.0.6
  API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.20.7
  Git commit:       1a79695
  Built:            Mon Sep  4 12:31:36 2023
  OS/Arch:          linux/arm64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.22
  GitCommit:        8165feabfdfe38c65b599c4993d227328c231fca
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.8
  GitCommit:        v1.1.8-0-g82f18fe
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
% minikube version
minikube version: v1.31.2
commit: fd7ecd9c4599bef9f04c0986c4a0187f98a4396e
% minikube start
  minikube v1.31.2 on Darwin 14.0 (arm64)
✨  Automatically selected the docker driver
  Using Docker Desktop driver with root privileges
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Pulling base image ...
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.27.4 preload ...
    > preloaded-images-k8s-v18-v1...:  327.74 MiB / 327.74 MiB  100.00% 2.32 Mi
    > gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase...:  404.50 MiB / 404.50 MiB  100.00% 2.60 Mi
  Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=4000MB) ...
  Preparing Kubernetes v1.27.4 on Docker 24.0.4 ...
    ▪ Generating certificates and keys ...
    ▪ Booting up control plane ...
    ▪ Configuring RBAC rules ...
  Configuring bridge CNI (Container Networking Interface) ...
  Verifying Kubernetes components...
    ▪ Using image gcr.io/k8s-minikube/storage-provisioner:v5
  Enabled addons: storage-provisioner, default-storageclass
  Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube" cluster and "default" namespace by default
% kubectl version
Client Version: v1.28.3
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.27.4
% nano kubernetes-minio.yaml
% cat kubernetes-minio.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  # This name uniquely identifies the PVC. Will be used in deployment below.
  name: minio-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: minio-storage-claim
spec:
  # Read more about access modes here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/#access-modes
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: standard
  resources:
    # This is the request for storage. Should be available in the cluster.
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1 #  for k8s versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2  and before 1.8.0 use extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  # This name uniquely identifies the Deployment
  name: minio-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minio
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        # Label is used as selector in the service.
        app: minio
    spec:
      # Refer to the PVC created earlier
      volumes:
      - name: storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          # Name of the PVC created earlier
          claimName: minio-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: minio
        # Pulls the default Minio image from Docker Hub
        image: minio/minio:latest
        args:
        - server
        - /storage
        env:
        # Minio access key and secret key
        - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
          value: "minio"
        - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
          value: "minio123"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
          hostPort: 9000
        # Mount the volume into the pod
        volumeMounts:
        - name: storage # must match the volume name, above
          mountPath: "/storage"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: minio
% kubectl apply -f kubernetes-minio.yaml
persistentvolumeclaim/minio-pv-claim created
deployment.apps/minio-deployment created
service/minio-service created
% kubectl get pods --watch  
NAME                                READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
minio-deployment-588b47b7c6-ss6ws   0/1     ContainerCreating   0          13s
minio-deployment-588b47b7c6-ss6ws   1/1     Running             0          16s
^C%                                                                                                                                                             % kubectl get pvc  minio-pv-claim
NAME             STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
minio-pv-claim   Bound    pvc-a0c1734c-e995-45ce-afb9-869ac9520458   10Gi       RWO            standard       29s
% kubectl get deployment minio-deployment
NAME               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
minio-deployment   1/1     1            1           43s
% kubectl get svc minio-service
NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
minio-service   LoadBalancer   10.109.120.194   <pending>     9000:30334/TCP   51s
% kubectl get all 
NAME                                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/minio-deployment-588b47b7c6-ss6ws   1/1     Running   0          59s

NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          7m27s
service/minio-service   LoadBalancer   10.109.120.194   <pending>     9000:30334/TCP   59s

NAME                               READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/minio-deployment   1/1     1            1           59s

NAME                                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/minio-deployment-588b47b7c6   1         1         1       59s
% minikube service minio-service
|-----------|---------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME      | TARGET PORT |            URL            |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|---------------------------|
| default   | minio-service |        9000 | http://192.168.49.2:30334 |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|---------------------------|
  Starting tunnel for service minio-service.
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |     NAME      | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | minio-service |             | http://127.0.0.1:52314 |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|------------------------|
  Opening service default/minio-service in default browser...
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

Comment: What if you run `kubectl port-forward svc/minio-service 32140`  and go to http://localhost:32140` .

Comment: Port forwarding doesn't help.